# Maintaining Queries in URL

Tags: query, urls

When I generate a lead I get the values passed on via the URL Query which is the following:

```
?fname=[value]&lname=[value]&email=[value]
```

I’d like to know how I can carry this query over to the next page as well? *(so the URL is passed over across two pages instead of just the one)*.

So it would flow like this:

```
LeadPageExample.com -> Lead entered details -> LeadPageExample.com/Upsell?fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com -> Lead clicks on cancel or add to cart (I want fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com to be passed on again) -> LeadPageExample.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=312&fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com
```

Essentially I want the `fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com` query to be re-attached to the next link and passed on twice in this scenario.

To illustrate:

```
LeadPageExample.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=312&fname=Alex&lname=Smith&email=asmith@email.com
```

Any ideas? Is it possible? If so, how?

To be even more specific, I ONLY want this to happen on specific webpages on my wordpress site.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: It partially depends on which links you want to apply the query to, and where those links are coming from. Alternatively you could do it in JavaScript, in which case WordPress would not really be involved. Frankly I think you'd be better off remembering these details in a cookie or local storage and then retrieiving them at the moment you need to use them.